# Use image scale and crop in custom function

Tags: media

In Drupal 7, I'm trying to use `image_scale_and_crop()` to take an image from an external URL and resize it.  Then I want to print it out to my page.  Here is my code:

```
$filename = $bjt_img;
$img_url = "http://www.mydomain.com/uploads/".$filename;
$myimg = image_load($img_url);
$myimg_scaled = image_scale_and_crop($myimg, 100, 80);

print '<img src="'.$myimg_scaled.'">'
```

I'm getting the message:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to image_scale_and_crop()
>   must be an instance of stdClass, boolean given, called in...

How exactly is the image returned with `image_scale_and_crop()`?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is image_load($img_url) is returning FALSE, which is not an object.

```
$filename = $bjt_img;
$img_url = "http://www.mydomain.com/uploads/".$filename;
if (isset($myimg = image_load($img_url)) {
  $myimg_scaled = image_scale_and_crop($myimg, 100, 80);
  print '<img src="'.$myimg_scaled.'">'
} 
else {
  print 'error'
}
```

Plus I think it must be a file,  not a url to a file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value returned from [image_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--image.inc/function/image_load/7), which is the boolean `FALSE` because the function is not able to load the image file.

> #### Return value
>
> An image object or `FALSE` if there was a problem loading the file. The image object has the following properties:
>
> - 'source' - The original file path.
> - 'info' - The array of information returned by `image_get_info()`
> - 'toolkit' - The name of the image toolkit requested when the image was loaded.

As for the parameters accepted from the function, the first one is the path to the image file, which normally doesn't mean the URL of the image. Check also that in your PHP installation, the file functions are allowed to open remote files; in the case it is not enabled, passing a URL when a function is expecting a file name would cause the error you noticed.

The documentation for [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php), which is the function that is called if the image toolkit Drupal is using is GD2, and the image is a JPEG one, reports:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

Similar warning is given for [imagecreatefrompng()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php), and the other `imagecreatefrom[image-type]()` functions.